# What can cause the type initializer for 'iText.Commons.Actions.EventManager' to throw an exception creating PdfDocument object in itext7?

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, kernel, itext7

Background: I created a custom Windows Service in C# .NET on Windows Server 2016 for loading data from various input data files. It polls inbox folders for files and loads their data to our databases. It has worked fine for years.

For PDF files we were using iTextSharp to scrape the XML from the form until it was deprecated. We purchased a commercial license for itext7 and updated to itext7 version 7.2.4 via NuGet.

The code runs with no issue via VS debugger, or as an executable on the server executed as Administrator, but as a Windows Service it gets the follow error when trying to create a PdfDocument object:

The type initializer for 'iText.Commons.Actions.EventManager' threw an exception.
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Open(PdfVersion newPdfVersion)

The code is so simple and I ensured the account the service executes under has file and folder access. I even added the account to the local administrators group and still does not work. My code is:

pdfFileToLoad is a string with a value like "C:\PDFFolder\pdfFileName.pdf"
xmlFile is a string with a value like "C:\XMLFolder\pdfFileName.xml"

```
                PdfReader pdfFileToRead = new PdfReader(pdfFileToLoad);
                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfFileToRead);
                PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
                XfaForm xfa = form.GetXfaForm();

                // Get XFA data under datasets/data.
                XElement node = xfa.GetDatasetsNode();
                IEnumerable<XNode> list = node.Nodes();
                foreach (XNode item in list)
                {
                    if (item is XElement && "data".Equals(((XElement)item).Name.LocalName))
                    {
                        node = (XElement)item;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlFile, settings);
                node.WriteTo(writer);
                writer.Close();

                pdfDoc.Close();
```

It gets the exception error at PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfFileToRead).

I have tried adding the account the service runs under to the local Administrators group. I have scoured the Internet but I am unable to see extended documentation on this error in itext7. I have also looked for documentation and/or examples on getting these exception details from iext7 to pass to my error handling, but the API documentation is basic.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or have information on extracting the exception messages for itext7?

Does anyone know what permissions does itext7 need on a Windows Server 2016 to properly execute? I do know Windows Server 2016 does have more security features especially when executing a Windows Service.

Comment: I have done more extensive testing and it is definitely not the code. Where I work, the local admin on the server does have some restrictions and Domain Admins have all permissions.

So it is looking like itext7 does require certain permissions or policy to be able to create/open a PdfDocument object that may be more restrictive on Windows Server 2016.

Does anyone know what these permissions/security policies are?

Comment: Since you are a paying iText customer, you should contact their support directly.

Comment: Actually, a commercial license does not have support. That has to be paid for separately. In fact, on their website they direct you to post here on Stack Overflow. I did send them an email to see if they will respond.